# Screen reader pronouncing state/country codes and numbers

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a table that contains location information. I wanted to hear how a screen reader would interpret my markup. Sure enough it read 'CA' as the letters C and A. It also did the same thing for the table cell with an age, it read '23' as 2 3. Is there a way to mark these items and others like that in a way that screen readers will read them as 'California' and 'twenty three' without actually spelling them out?

EDIT: Added the  `title` attr alongside with the regular text. The screenreader reads: "Age, group, twenty three, 2 3"

I also tried adding an `aria-hidden="true"` to a span nested inside of the `<td>` but it completely skipped the `td` and the `span` and moved onto the next element.

Markup:

```
     <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">First Name</th>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Age</th>
                <td title="Twenty Three">23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">State</th>
                <td tithe="California">CA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

ARIA-hidden:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Age</th>
                <td title="Twenty Three"><span aria-hidden="true">23</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use a `title` attribute to make it easyer for people with screen readers

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">First Name</th>
            <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Age</th>
            <td title="twentythree">23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">State</th>
            <td title="California">CA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A screen reader will read the title text rather then the content, so you can add screen reader friendly text for any table cell

Comment: Ah of course, I read [this](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/) a while back and I guess I've shied away from using it. But this seems like the perfect use case.

Comment: yeah I guess he's talking about abuse for a slightly different goal to accessibility. If the site needs to be accessible then it's (IMHO) the best solution. glad I could help

Comment: So I tried that out, but now it reads both the title attr and other text. I'm going to try just adding aria hidden on span elements on the times I don't need read. But I feel like there's a more robust solution.

Comment: that's odd, thanks for the update. what screen reader are you using?

Comment: The [`title` attribute is not reliably announced](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/) so beware.

Comment: I'm using voiceover. @atmd